# Sticky header causes page "jumps" when short page

Tags: jquery, css, header

I've managed to do a sticky header which works fine, apart from the fact, that when page isn't long enough it keeps "jumping". How to make it working properly?
Here is some code, jsfiddle and the most important: A VIDEO - which presents what the problem is. JS fiddle may not show if you have smaller resolution screens. Please see the video. How to fix this issue? I ran out of ideas.

Please see this video: [video here](https://vimeo.com/141230862)

also code here:

```
<div id="ontop">floating heading</div>
<header>sticky heading</header>
<div id="wrapper"> 
    1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
</div>

#ontop {width:100%; height:80px; background-color:yellow;}
header {width:100%; height:400px; background-color:lightgrey; }
#wrapper {background-color:lightblue; height:200px;}

.navfixed {position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width:100%; display:block; margin-bottom:120px; } 
.wrapperBelow{margin-top:22px;}


$(function () {
    var elem = $('header'),
        wrapperElem = $('#wrapper'),
        elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        elem.toggleClass('navfixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
         wrapperElem.toggleClass('wrapperBelow', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    }).scroll();
});
```

and fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/5vhbv0dL/2/)

Comment: take a look at this site - http://health-insure1.co.uk  .. Are you trying to get menu like that website?

Comment: no @XahedKamal, this is something different. Please take a look on the answer below. I will check that solution later tonight, I think it should sort the problem out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/59fbyyg0/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="stickyheader"></div>
<div id="content2"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: gold;    
}

.headerstuck{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#stickyheader{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: DarkOrange;
}

#content{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #ccc;

}

#content2{
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
   background-color: #ccc;

}

#footer{
   width: 100%;
   height: 250px;
   background: DodgerBlue;

}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){  
    $('#stickyheader').addClass("headerstuck");
  }
  else{
    $('#stickyheader').removeClass("headerstuck");
  }
});
```

//EDIT----
Fixes the content moving up when changing header div to fixed:

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/59fbyyg0/5/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
<div id="content">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
<div id="stickyheader">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
<div id="content2">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
<div id="footer">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: gold;    
}

#stickyheader{
   position:absolute;
   top:300px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: DarkOrange;
}

#content{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #ccc;

}

#content2{
   margin-top:100px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
   background-color: white;

}

#footer{
   width: 100%;
   height: 250px;
   background: DodgerBlue;

}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){  
    $("#stickyheader").css({"position":"fixed", "top":"0"});
  }
  else{
    $("#stickyheader").css({"position":"", "top":""});
  }
});
```

Comment: actually it doesn't sort the problem. if you make the preview area smaller it still jumps. It happens when header starts sticking and the footer is too small to cover the rest of the screen.

Comment: Don't know what you mean with preview area,  if you modify my jsfiddle demo your way so you get the issue then post the link as comment so I can take a look it at try see whats wrong.

Comment: if you can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/59fbyyg0/3/ you will notice than when scrolling down numbers on white content2 area disappear behind the header and I wanted to be fluent, like in my question. The way you done it doesn't include the margin-top on content2 and this causes the problem explained in the question. That adding a margin-top to content2 becomes an issue - then page jumps.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now, I have updated the post with some new code and demo, think that should address your issue with the content "jumping", also a good way to test it is to hold down the scroll wheel and drag the page so you have smooth "scrolling" so you don't get "jumping" from the scroll steps, unless of course you have a mouse with smooth scroll.

Comment: thanks it seems this is working OK. Great work, thanks. I will test that later tonight on the actual website and if it works ok, I will mark your answer as accepted and closed :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set min-heights on your content areas try this.
`body {min-height: 75rem;}`

Comment: Can you explain why use 75?

Comment: I got that number looking at an example of a sticky nav for bootstrap. It might need to be adjusted depending on your site. I ended up upping it to 80rem.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/